# Safety of unplugging while device is switched on

Tags: switches, power-electronics, safety, socket

Help resolve a debate: is it less safe to switch off devices at the wall socket rather than using the off button on the device?

He says it’s equally safe to just switch on and off it even just unplug the device while it’s running.

I was brought up with the ‘urban myth’ that it’s somehow unsafe to just unplug things that are running, or switch on and off at the wall with the device left switched on (e.g., a TV, hairdryer, sander, drill).

Comment: What do you mean specifically when you say safety or safe? Safety or safe usually refers to a person i.e. if an action might be hazardous to a person.

Comment: Before someone else or I writes a long-winded answer: this depends on what you agree on that "safety" means, so please add that to your question. Also, it depends on what classes of devices you mean: a 5W lamp will behave differently to a washing machine at full load close to maximum rotational speed. And if course, industrial machines are a different business, but you're probably not referring to these. So, please do add to your question what devices you care about! Then, it is of lesser importance, but do tell us about the type of plugs and grid - i.e., which location you're in.

Comment: This can also be considered safety if it gets bad enough. I try to avoid excessive plugging/unplugging because it wears down the outlet and eventually gets more loose when grabbing onto plugs. If the inserted plugs sag enough they can make intermittent sparking connections and/or the exposed plug contacts are unsafe for children who can reach them. This is why for small appliances like toaster ovens and rice cookers I like using a switched outlet adapter like this. https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01894YMX4/

Answer (score 3):

Some devices perform a sequence of operations prior to shut down, if they are shut down via their own switch. In that case the preferred method of shut down is via the device's switch. Computers are an obvious example.

Other devices perform a sequence of operations prior to shut down if they detect loss of power. They use the reserve energy stored in capacitors to perform these operations before the power is completely gone. For these devices, it doesn't matter whether power is lost by a power switch on the device, pulling the plug, or a switch controlling the power outlet.

A third class, of devices that includes many home appliances, is not designed to perform any shut-down tasks. Like the previous case, it doesn't matter whether power is cut off via a switch on the device, pulling the plug, or a switch controlling the outlet.

However, in all cases, switches are *designed* for cutting off power without damage to themselves. Cords and plugs may not be. Although pulling the plug may work, there may be arcing, which can shorten the life of the plug or receptacle. Pulling on a cord may also damage it.